# How can I loop through a nested array within an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So this is the JSON file with 3 objects

```
export const Projects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Site 1',
    tech: [
      'HTML',
      'CSS',
      'SASS',
      'React'
    ],
    description: 'Lorem1',
    image: '/Image4.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Site 2',
    tech: [
      'HTML',
      'CSS',
      'SASS',
      'React'
    ],
    description: 'Lorem2',
    image: '/Image4.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Site 3',
    tech: [
      'HTML',
      'CSS',
      'SASS',
      'React'
    ],
    description: 'Lorem3',
    image: '/Image4.jpg'

  }
];
```

I am trying to loop through the 'tech' arrays and return each item on its own. When I loop through them, right now I only get the full array and I can only put them all into a single div. This is how currently I do it and it works fine with the other parts, however, how can I receive the "tech" part with individual objects, rather than just the one array?

```
const Portfolio = () => {
   const portfolioItem = Projects.map((project, i) => {
     return <Item
     key={i}
     image={Projects[i].image}
     description={Projects[i].description}
     name={Projects[i].name}
     tech={Projects[i].tech}  
     />
   })
```

Comment: So what do want now. it is not clear

Comment: what is `Item`? if your custom component, you will need to handle `tech` inside that component (please share your code). if it comes from some library, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that rendering of `tech` prop is implemented in a simple way, like this:

```
const Item = ({tech}) => <div>{tech}</div>
```

Then you can map the array of strings into an array of React elements:

```
<Item
  key={i}
  image={Projects[i].image}
  description={Projects[i].description}
  name={Projects[i].name}
  tech={Projects[i].tech.map((t) => <span>{t}</span>)}  
/>
```

Alternatively, you can convert the array to a single string, with explicit separator:

```
     tech={Projects[i].tech.join(', ')}
```

Comment: Hey, I was just about to post the example code of Item component. Your assumption  was correct and your answer was exactly what I was looking for! I was massively overthinking this and was going for way too complicated solution. Thank you very much!